# How can I manually test AngularJS directives and Jasmine tests written in CoffeeScript?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, rubygems, jasmine

I am writing a Ruby gem where in I provide many angular directives.

Directives are written using the following folder structure, e.g.

```
app
 - assets
   - javascripts
     - components
        - dropdown
          - dropdown.html
          - dropdown.service.coffee
          - index.coffee (this has directive code)
spec
 - javascripts
   - dropdown
     - dropdown.service_spec.coffee (jasmine test)
```

Now since this is a gem, I want to keep it so and not make it a Rails app. It will make it harder for people to use it as gem

But I want to able to test the directives. I cannot do so automatically.

I want to know how can I run these Jasmine tests written in coffeescript locally/ manually by firing up an HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a HTML file that adds your files, jasmine, and run tests.

Instead of doing that yourself, you can use one of the numerous existing boilerplates, like this one:

https://github.com/andrewvida/coffeescript-jasmine-boilerplate